# Powershell - Remove space between two variables

Tags: powershell

I have two array's which contain a selection of strings with information taken from a text file. I then use a For Loop to loop through both arrays and print out the strings together, which happen to create a folder destination and file name.

```
Get-Content .\PostBackupCheck-TextFile.txt | ForEach-Object { $a = $_ -split ' ' ; $locationArray += "$($a[0]):\$($a[1])\" ; $imageArray += "$($a[2])_$($a[3])_VOL_b00$($a[4])_i000.spi" }
```

The above takes a text file, splits it into separate parts, stores some into the `locationArray` and other information in the `imageArray`, like this:

`locationArray[0]` would be `L:\Place\`

`imageArray[0]` would be `SERVERNAME_C_VOL_b001_i005.spi`

Then I run a For Loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $imageArray.Length - 1; $i++) 
    {Write-Host $locationArray[$i]$imageArray[$i]}
```

But it places a space between the `L:\Place\` and  the `SERVERNAME_C_VOL_b001_i005.spi`

So it becomes: `L:\Place\ SERVERNAME_C_VOL_b001_i005.spi`

Instead, it should be: `L:\Place\SERVERNAME_C_VOL_b001_i005.spi`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1** - for best readability:

```
{Write-Host ("{0}{1}" -f $locationArray[$i], $imageArray[$i]) }
```

**Option #2** - slightly confusing, less readable:

```
{Write-Host "$($locationArray[$i])$($imageArray[$i])" }
```

**Option #3** - more readable than #2, but more lines:

```
{
  $location = $locationArray[$i];
  $image = $imageArray[$i];
  Write-Host "$location$image";
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly ! I'm fairly new to Powershell though, what exactly does that do?

Comment: @TheD: `-f` is a Powershell way to do [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). You can put some static text in between {0} and {1} and it's very readable. Option #2 is to escape your variables, for this you need many dollar signs, and it's harder to read and comprehend.

Comment: @TheD: no problem, also check option #3 I just added. :)

Comment: I'd consider Option 2 to be more readable than Option 1, personally, but I always find the `-f` format operator ridiculously non-intuitive.  There ought to be a command `Format-String` or something.  It's aberrant enough to be distasteful to me.

Comment: @BaconBits I think it's just a matter of habit, but if you come from a .Net environment `-f` is much appreciated.

Comment: @Christian That's just it, though. The audience for PowerShell is system administrators, not software developers. It would be preferable to use something like `Format-String -Format "{0}{1}" -String $locationArray[$i], $imageArray[$i] | Write-Host`.  yes, it's more verbose, but the `-f` operator breaks the design consistency for PowerShell. It's like Python's `print` function in 2.x not using parentheses. How often have you been frustrated looking for the `Get-Help` entry for `-f` because it's not a command? You know it's there and still struggle to find it. That's just stupid.

Comment: @BaconBits: depending on how long the line is, and how many variables need escaping, you might well get lost in those `$` signs and brackets, especially after a hard working day. But it is indeed a matter of personal choice. Regarding `-f` being not self-explainable, well as Christian pointed out - it is fine if you come from .NET background. Powershell is a language of many flavors - you just pick one that suits you.

Comment: @BaconBits I'm never been frustrated... I'm a lucky sysadmin with a good .net background :). But yes `-f` is hard to find in help and in google too. Anyway for future comments's readers you can read about `-f` doing `get-help about_Operators`.